# need to process files based on arrival time using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

I receive 5 to 6 files daily. The file names are in the format `XXXXX_DDMM_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.csv`.

Examples:

- A file generated Oct 17th 2016 at 03:12:32 pm is named `XXXXX_17OCT_20161017151232.csv`.
- A file generated Oct 16th 2016 at 03:04:23 pm is named `XXXXX_16OCT_20161016150423.csv`.
- A file generated Oct 18th 2016 at 02:34:56 pm is named `XXXXX_18OCT_20161018143456.csv`.

I need to move all the files to a folder named `TEST1` and from there I need to find the first file which has the oldest timestamp, process it, and then delete that file from the folder.

Next need to pick second oldest timestamp and repeat the process for all files.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The classic method is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od "test1\*.csv"') do echo %%a
```

which will `echo` the filenames matching the mask `test1\*.csv` in `/od` order-of-date.

This should do what you want (well, select the files in order - the processing is your affair...) but if you really want to process the files according to their names where `X*` is unknown (but a constant length (of 5)) then

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "test1\*.csv"^|sort /+11 ') do echo %%a
```

should work - sorting the list of raw filenames on the 11th column onward.

Answer (score 0):

[Magoo's 2nd solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40265730/1012053) works great if and only if the length of XXXXX is constant. But if it can vary, then SORT will not do you any good.

I have written [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5595) to handle complex sorting scenarios that are beyond the capability of the native SORT command. It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

Use `jsort /?` from the command prompt to get help.

In this solution, I sort based on the text that appears after the last `_` in the file name. So this solution works properly, even if XXXXX contains `_` within it.

```
pushd "\test1"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d "test1\*.csv"^|jsort /d _ /t -1'
) do (
  REM process the %%F file
  del "%%F"
)
popd
```

Comment: I have taken sample Files:D:\test1\AXXX_17OCT_20161017151232.csv
D:\test1\BXXX_16OCT_20161016150423.csv
D:\test1\GXXX_18OCT_20161018143456.csv and modified the script accordingly.:@echo off
set src=D:\test1\*.csv
set dest=D:\test2\
move %src% %dest%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
'dir /b "%dest%\*.csv"^|sort /+11 '
) do (rem process the %%a file
 del %dest%\"%%a"). Files are not sorted  and deleting all the files at a time.If I run the script for the first time it should delete only one file based on old timestamp and in next run it should delete second and so on..can you please help here.

Comment: @user3051956 - You said you wanted to process all files, which is what the loop does. However, it is processing them in the correct order. `echo %%F` within the loop, and you will see that the list is indeed sorted.

Comment: @user3051956 - Don't put complicated new requests in comments. Ask a new question. Or if you are truly refining your original question, edit your question, and perhaps add a comment to existing answers saying you have done so. But be warned, people that answer do not like constantly evolving questions. Spend more time up front thinking about your problem and what your specific question is before you post, and be precise. I probably will not look at this question any more.